# How can I convert my div rows into columns in grid structure in mobile viewport using css?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML code and I want to convert all the rows into columns.
code -

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper .first {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For desktop the output is  -

```
A B C
A B C
A B C
```

For mobile viewport I want output something like -

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

The desktop output is correct. Can anyone help me achieving the above output in case of mobile viewport ?

Answer (score 1):

Will this do? I've applied a grid to the main wrapper but they won't get aligned row by row if the row heights are different

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  }
  .main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.wrapper > div {
 border: 1px solid gray;
}

.first {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.second {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.third {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edited to add** to stack each columns above each other on small screen sizes use the following:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    
    /* use this if you want all the rows the same height, otherwise delete this declaration */
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    
    /* this pops a small margin at the bottom of each margin. Delete if not needed*/
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.first {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.second {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.third {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the design for mobile viewport. There was a slight change introduced. Can you help me for the above design in mobile viewport ?

Comment: I've added an example to show you how with some options that you can delete depending on what behaviour you want.  Any issues drop a comment below.

Comment: I got your point what you are saying, But what if I want 
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
in a single column in mobile view port. I have updated the mobile viewport design for your reference, then how can I achieve it ?